# need the logical meaning of app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname , 'views'))

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is the server and I use the `pug` template `engine init`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const port = 80;

//Express specific stuff 
app.use('/static' , express.static('static')) //For serving static files



//Pug specific stuff
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); //set the template engine as pug
app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname , 'views')) //set the views directory




//End points
app.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
  res.status(200).render('index.pug')
})

//start the server
app.listen(port , ()=>{
  console.log(`The application is running at port${port}`)
})
```

What I want to know is just what is the role of

```
app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname , 'views'))
```

does it means connecting the views folder to the app??

Answer (score 0):

based on [express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) documentation

**app.set(name, value)**

> Assigns setting name to value. You may store any value that you want, but certain names can be used to configure the behavior of the server. These special names are listed in the app settings table

so when you want use `pug` you should create a sub-directory inside the root directory for keeping `.pug` template files, say, `/views`.

There are two additional lines of code to be inserted into our Express.js main file, both involving the `app.set()` method with properties `views` and `view engine`. The `views` property points to the directory (or array of directories) where the templates are kept and the `view engine` property assigns the template engine to use

Comment: can you please interprete this also?                                                                   
        app.use('/static' , express.static('static')) //For serving static files                               Thanks